# Node npm package throw use strict: command not found after publish and install globaly

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to publish npm package, when i am install the package globally and try to run the cli command i get this errors:

```
/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/bin/myPack: line 1: use strict: command not found
/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/bin/myPack: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/bin/myPack: line 3: `var _commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args');'
```

The top of the file that the error refer to:

```
'use strict';

var _commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args');

var _commandLineArgs2 = _interopRequireDefault(_commandLineArgs);
```

The package.json bin section:

```
  "bin": {
    "myPack": "dist/myPack.js"
  }
```

When i am running this in my local development this works well, what is the problem?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Your script should start with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line, otherwise it will be executed as a shell script (hence the errors).

Add this as first line to `dist/myPack.js`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Comment: This also works with .ts files, unbelievable.

Comment: Well, this works with .foobar files as well; the extension is just a convention to indicate the type of a file in its name and it has no effect on how the file is actually run.

Comment: This works, but my dist is transpiled from TypeScript on the build. Shouldn't this be automatic somehow? In my case, I'm using `npm link` with a `bin: {}` setting to test as if it was local. Perhaps this problem goes away when one publishes with npm? I guess I didn't want to take the risk of a bad publish.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator do you mean that transpiling causes the comment to be removed? I've run a little test, and running `tsc test.ts` creates a `test.js` file that leaves the comment alone, so the `.js` file (when made executable) works as expected.

Comment: Is the comment in the typescript file? My dist/ is ignored in git

Comment: @Fuhrmanator yes, the comment is in the `.ts` file, and after transpiling it's also in the `.js` file.