# why am I getting javascript error: use strict: not found and Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, strict

Compiling Script files using **npm start**, getting errors: **use strict: not found**
**Syntax error: "(" unexpected** or **Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")**

Here is my code, index.js:

```
"use strict";
const getBtnEvent = document.querySelector("button");
getBtnEvent === null || getBtnEvent === void 0 ? void 0 : getBtnEvent.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Clicked the button' + getBtnEvent);
});
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

I've been using ES6 for above code and node version 18.*

checked for javascript version, npm start file, npm  dependencies

Comment: What does `npm start` do? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353512/node-npm-package-throw-use-strict-command-not-found-after-publish-and-install-g

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros, That helps a lot, I've initiated learning typescript, and included tsconfig.json with ES6 and while compiling .ts files, it's working. I wanted to use npm start for initiating with a predefined script in package.json